# Why does TypeScript use "type annotations" instead of keywords like other strongly-typed languages?

Tags: syntax, typescript, strong-typing

TypeScript's type system uses *type annotations*, which look like this:

```
private currentState: IAppState;
```

I read this as "currentState is an IAppState"

Why does this syntax make more design sense than this, which is what I'm used to from other strongly-typed languages?

```
private IAppState currentState;
```

I understand that TypeScript is supposed to be an *extension* of JavaScript syntax, but in that case, what made the designers of TypeScript choose the current syntax over this:

```
private IAppState: currentState;
```

Comment: I have no idea, but since types are not mandatory, consider this: `function fn(value1: MyType1, value2: MyType2)` vs `function fn(MyType1 value1, MyType2 value2)`, now if I decide to remove one of the types: `function fn(value1: MyType1, value2)` vs `function fn(MyType1 value1, value2)`. The later looks a bit weird, as opposed  to how it is in typescript. Also, some languages had this syntax before typescript, for example `ActionScript`.

Comment: There are other strongly typed languages that seem to have influenced typescript as well. OCaml and Haskell are probably the two most famous strongly typed functional languages and they have this syntax (though haskell uses two colons)

Comment: The team's active on here so one of them may drop by your post and give the background and they'd be much better equipped to speak about it, I just wanted to say that there is definitely precedent.

Comment: Also, this was the syntax used by ECMAScript 4 (implemented by ActionScript 3 but never by JavaScript), so I would be surprised if the TypeScript team didn't consider this as design precedent to follow.

Answer (score 0):

A friend and I were discussing it and he raised a good example:

```js
type student_detail = {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  percentage: number,
  clg_data: {
    college_id: number,
    college_name: string
  }
}
```

This almost looks like standard JS. Now imagine what you'd have with C style syntax:

```c
struct student_detail {
    number id;
    string name;
    number percentage;
    // structure within structure
    struct {
        number college_id;
        string college_name;
    } clg_data;
}
```

When it comes to structures in structures the only way to really do it is by splitting them out into separate structures:

```c
struct student_college_detail {
    number college_id;
    string college_name;
};
struct student_detail {
    number id;
    string name;
    number percentage;
    struct student_college_detail clg_data;
}
```

This is fine but doesn't really fit into JavaScript. This is likely the reason why they stuck with the `var: type` syntax. It would maybe be nice if you could do either though. :)